# checking expiration of custom auth token client side

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

Using firebase, can I check to see if a cached custom auth token on the ios client is expired before I make the authWithCustomToken request?  If not, is there a specific expired exception that gets returned so that I can know whether to redirect them to re-authenticate, or to throw an error.

Comment: Is something wrong with [the `expires` property](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/login/password.html#section-logging-in)? The [error listing](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/user-auth.html#section-full-error) suggests that `FAuthenticationErrorInvalidCredentials` covers this use case.

Comment: what object is the expires property on?

Comment: It's stored in the `authData` object described here: https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/user-auth.html#section-monitoring-authentication

Comment: but that's only accessible as a callback during the creating of the token, the authData object is not accessible after the token has been created.  I suppose I can keep the authData with the token but am looking for a more durable solution.

Comment: AuthData can be accessed by using the getAuth() and onAuth() methods at any time.

Comment: my scenario is when the user is not authenticated, e.g. starting the app after time goes by and trying to use an expired or cached auth token - in which case the authData should be null

Comment: If you can't figure out how to store the expires value by using `authData`, You can directly read it by [parsing the token](http://jsfiddle.net/firebase/XDXu5/embedded/result/).